# How to run tasks based on groups in ansible

Tags: ansible

I need to run few tasks based on groupname remaining tasks should execute normal way
ex: one  task with variable called bootstrap now i need to run this task only if hostgroup contains group called bootstrap

```
ex: task1: echo "bootstrap node" >> bootstrap

inventory file
[bootstrap]
ip1
ip2
ip3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a play directly for that group

```yaml
---
- name: Play to group bootstrap
  hosts: bootstrap

  tasks
  - name: Example of task
    debug:
      msg: Example of a task
```

but if you need run some tasks for specific group use `when: "'bootstrap' in group_name"` as below

```yaml
---
- name: Play to group bootstrap
  hosts: bootstrap

  tasks
  - name: Example of task for all
    debug:
      msg: Example of running a task for all

  - name: Example of task for bootstrap
    debug:
      msg: Example of running a task for bootstrap
    when: "'bootstrap' in group_name"
```

If there are a lot of tasks you can use block as below

```yaml
---
- name: Play to group bootstrap
  hosts: bootstrap

  tasks
  - name: Example of task for all
    debug:
      msg: Example of running a task for all

  - name: Block for bootstrap
    block:
      - name: Example of task 1 for bootstrap
        debug:
          msg: Example of running a task 1 for bootstrap

      - name: Example of task 2 for bootstrap
        debug:
          msg: Example of running a task 2 for bootstrap

      - name: Example of task 3 for bootstrap
        debug:
          msg: Example of running a task 3 for bootstrap

    when: "'bootstrap' in group_name"
```

Comment: and,``edjx node gen-env {{ CERTIFICATES }}/private.pem -i $ip -o runtime/.env -w {{ WRITER_NODE_ID }} -b {{ BOOTSTRAP_NODE_ADDRESS }} --dns --greedy --bootstrap``` i need to run this coomand but the last 3 flags  `should run based on user i/o. & should run only onetime since runtime/.env will override all values based on flags. so user wants to run with bootstrap & dns then only these flags should pass to this command.  question for prompt for these values like do you want to run with bootstrap? yes or no if yes then that flag should added to that command if no shouldnt add.